# Copy of array is altering original

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two controllers. The first controller loads a list from a server and creates a list of custom objects, `WordList`.

```
class WordList {

    let name: String
    let releaseDate: Date
    var words: [String]
    let multiplier: Int

    ...
}
```

On the first screen, the user is given the option to select lists before moving on. On the next controller, a random word is selected from a random list. After the word is presented, it is removed while the user interacts with it. Once the user is don interacting, a new word is chosen until there are no more. If I go back to the main controller and select the same list that I just worked with, the list will be empty. This is how I'm sending the selected items.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? WordController {
        var wordLists = [WordList]()

        for index in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! {
            wordLists.append(lists[index.row]) // lists is a class property that is a WordList array.
        }

        // This was my first attempt. Values were copied but removed from this controller.
        // for wordList in wordLists {
        //   destination.wordLists.append(wordList)
        // }

        // destination.wordLists = wordLists

        // This was my second attempt. Values were also copied but removed from this controller.
        destination.wordLists.append(contentsOf: wordLists)
    }
}
```

I understand that I must be passing a reference of the list instead of actually copying it, but I didn't think that that would be how it would work if I'm populating the second array by copying values from the first.

Other than reloading the first controller every time the user returns to the screen, how can I have this work so that a user can reuse a list that has been cleared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

> I understand that I must be passing a reference of the list instead of actually copying it ...

No, you are passing a new array.

> ... but I didn't think that that would be how it would work if I'm populating the second array by copying values from the first.

Unfortunately, you're not "copying values" from the first array, but copying the `WordList` references from the first array into the second array. Bottom line, the problem isn't the `Array`, which is a value type, but rather `WordList`, which is a reference type.

`WordList` is a reference type by virtue of its being a `class`. So, when you take a reference to a `WordList` from one array and add it to another array, that second array will still reference the same `WordList` instances.

If you don't want your manipulation of that other array's instances to affect the original instances, you can either:

- change `WordList` from a reference type (a `class`) to a value type (a `struct`):

  ```
  struct WordList {
      let name: String
      let releaseDate: Date
      var words: [String]
      let multiplier: Int
  }
  ```
- if you *really* need to use a `class`, write your own `copy` method that returns a new instance. For example, you might conform to `NSCopying` and write a `copy(with:)`:

  ```
  extension WordList: NSCopying {
      func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
          return WordList(name: name, releaseDate: releaseDate, words: words, multiplier: multiplier)
      }
  }
  ```

  and then when you build your new array, append copies rather than references to the original instances:

  ```
  for index in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! {
      wordLists.append(lists[index.row].copy() as! WordList)
  }
  ```

---

If you don't like the fact that `NSCopying` introduces that awkward `Any` return type for `copy`, you could also just define your `copy` method or even write your own `Copying` protocol, e.g.:

```
protocol Copying {
    associatedtype ObjectType = Self
    func copy() -> ObjectType
}

extension WordList: Copying {
    func copy() -> WordList {
        return WordList(name: name, releaseDate: releaseDate, words: words, multiplier: multiplier)
    }
}
```

and then you can do the following, with no cast needed:

```
for index in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! {
    wordLists.append(lists[index.row].copy())
}
```

Comment: I would avoid NSCopying because the only point of that protocol is to support NSObject.copy. It also introduces Any type without need.

Comment: The `NSCopying` protocol has no requirements that it's only for `NSObject` subclasses (e.g. if it really was for `NSObject` only, it would have `NSObjectProtocol` requirement). But I admittedly find `NSCopying`'s use of `Any` return type a bit unswifty. You could always define your own `Copying` protocol. I just hate introducing another largely duplicative protocol/method when there's an existing protocol designed for this purpose.

Comment: There is no actual need for a copying protocol. The protocol exists only because `NSObject` has a `copy` method with throws an exception when the instance does not conform to `NSCopying` and calls `copy(withZone:)` otherwise. The original reason was probably the need for `copy` properties but in Swift I would just declare a copy constructor (initalizer).

Comment: I agree that you don't _need_ a protocol for this (hence my comment about the fact that you "could just define your `copy` method"), but it seems like best practice, IMHO, to define protocols for these common, abstract patterns. It makes the intent explicit in the interface. But you certainly don't have to use protocol for this. It's a matter of personal preference. Frankly, I think the point here is a bit moot, as this strikes me that the first option, to make it a `struct`, a value type, is probably best.